# регулярные выражение js заданым требованиям

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Соответствие выражения заданным требованиям:

```
   - Минимальная длина – 6 символов
   - максимальная длина -10 символов
   - стартует с A-Z
   - Латиница
   - UPPER CASE
   - исключить спец символы (типа *, ?, % и тд.)
```

получилось сделать регулярку самому такого вида,
`!/^[A-Z\d\-\_\.]{6,10}$/` 
моё выражение учитывает все условия кроме "стартует с A-Z" , оно может стартовать как с A-Z так и с 0-9...

как учесть в ней чтоб ввод был доступен только с букв латиницей в верхнем регистре?
сейчас у меня и буквы и цифры вначале строки, нужно чтоб строка начиналась только с букв , а дальше или буквы или цифры, так же возможен "_"  между ними.
Примеры для тестирования :

CONT3_14

UNL_A_IT1

SLPU39_09

CONT1_14

CONT2_14

Буду благодарен за помощь, знающие люди, предложите свои варианты выражения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто в начале указать что первым символом должна идти буква латинского алфавита в верхнем регистре `[A-Z]` при этом надо уменьшить квантификатор с `{6,10}` на `{5,9}`.

Пример:

```js
const reg = /^[A-Z][A-Z\d_.-]{5,9}$/gm;
const str = `1ONT3_14
UNL_A_IT1
SLPU39_09
CONT1_14
CONT2_14`;
console.log(str.match(reg));
```

Comment: тоже думал уменьшить квантификаторы,  пока этот вариант меня устраивает, спасибо большое!)

Comment: @StanislavPro это самое простое решение, можно еще использовать позитивный просмотр вперед `^(?=[A-Z])[A-Z\d_.-]{6,10}$` тогда квантификатор на вторую группу символов менять не нужно, но в этом особо никакого смысла нет.